# Opening a new window in WPF withoug using .show()?

Tags: c#, wpf

It seems to be possible in this [project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4256111/MultiThreading.zip)...

After they use `pd = new ProgressDialog();`, the new window appears.

How did they do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define next instances first:

```
BackgroundWorker worker;
ProgressDialog pd;
```

then show a form through the `ShowDialog()` method in the click handler:

```
private void btnReportProgress_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int maxRecords = 1000;
    pd = new ProgressDialog();
    // doing something more...
    pd.ShowDialog();
}
```

`ProgressDialog.xaml.cs` class could have additional properties:

```
public string ProgressText
public int ProgressValue
```

Comment: I see.. can we say that .Show() means the 2 windows are independent whereas .ShowDialog() means the child is dependent on the parent?

Comment: @yeeen Yes. For example property WindowStartupLocation ProgressDialog forms can be set CenterOwner. Then ProgressDialog will start in the center of the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

pd.ShowDialog() is the last line of the btnReportProgress_Click function. It shows modal dialog, which is closed when the worker thread is completed, see worker.RunWorkerCompleted event subscription.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe they call `this.Show()` in the constructor of `ProgressDialog` class.